# Django update password made last_name empty

Tags: python, django, patch

I'm using `UserProfileSerializer` to validate fields in `patch` request:

```
password = request.data.get('password', '')
if password:
    if len(password) < 6:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    hashed_pass = make_password(password)
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(instance=user,
                                       data={'last_name': request.data.get('last_name', ''),
                                             'password': hashed_pass,
                                       partial=True)
else:
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
     serializer.save()
```

and this is my serializer:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    class meta:
        abstract = True

    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)], blank=True)


class UserProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

When i'm updating password, the `last_name` made empty!!

How i prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code (which is syntactically invalid (I assume you copy pasted incorrectly)) is to blame

```
data={'last_name': request.data.get('last_name', ''), 
      'password': hashed_pass,
                                       partial=True)
```

If the last name is not in the post data you are setting the last name to blank. You were probably looking for something like:

```
data={'last_name': request.data.get('last_name', user.last_name), 
      'password': hashed_pass}
```

which results in the current last name being preserved.

Comment: That means the second argument of `request.data.get()` is the default value of column, correct?

Comment: Should i remove the `partial=True` or not?

Comment: It isn't strictly needed because you are providing data for all the fields